# How do we separate the Joseph tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I realize that I tagged a question about "Joseph" (in-Genesis) (the one in Genesis) with the same tag as Joseph, the husband-of-mary. How should we disambiguate the two?

---

2020 Edit, I (moderator Peter, not the late great Affable Geek) was looking at tag synomyms and I think we should have taken his advice a long time ago.  There are very few questions about the patriarch Joseph and a large handful of questions about the foster father of Jesus Joseph.  Tagging is essentially broken here.

Comment: We had the [same problem](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/253/68) at Hermeneutics, for what it's worth.

Comment: @JonEricson: I'd forgotten about that; but I don't think either answer there applies here. Interesting case study on how these sites differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to propose:

- joseph-son-of-jacob
- joseph-husband-of-mary

As two separate tag.

The question then is, how do we disallow "joseph" as a tag?

(yeah, Joseph-wife-of-Mary isn't all that great...)

Comment: We can blacklist a tag if it becomes problematic, but for now I think re-tagging everything one way or the other will be enough to fix the problem as it will auto-complete for people who try to type it in and only higher rep users  who are likely to be more aware can create new tags anyway.

Comment: wife of Mary... I don't recall that one in [his litany](http://www.ewtn.com/devotionals/litanies/joseph.htm) ;).

Comment: FYI, I've gone ahead and separated according to the above

Answer (score 4):

How about just plain old [saint-joseph](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saint-joseph), or at the very most [joseph-of-nazareth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-of-nazareth).

OT Joseph probably can stay [joseph](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph) or [go-go-go-joe](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-go-go-joe).

Comment: My daughter and I can sing half that musical by heart...

Comment: I actually like [tag:josheph-of-nazareth], but I think not also being specific about the other tag will lead to trouble. If we make one specific, we have to do the others as well and avoid the use of a possibly ambiguous general tag.

Comment: @Peter Turner If more questions are tied to Joseph OT, then I like your suggestion (saint-joseph and joseph).  If more questions are tied to Joseph NT, then create "joseph-son-of-jacob" or "joseph-genesis" or "joseph-ot", then retag some questions.  Both tag summaries should make it clear of the existence of the two joseph tags to prevent mistagging.

Answer (score 1):

How about [joseph-ot](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-ot) and [joseph-nt](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-nt)?

Or [joseph-genesis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-genesis) and [joseph-gospels](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joseph-gospels)?